# Binary Search Time Complexity: Why does base 2 does not matter in log base 2 of n?

Tags: search, time, binary, complexity-theory, logarithm

Binary search time is often described as log base 2 of n. How come the base 2 is often discarded like in this video?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3YID7liBug

Comment: This is not a complete question IMO, because guessing at what you are trying to ask would involve sitting through a 6 minute HackerRank YouTube video.  Your question needs to stand on its own two legs.  Get to the point and tell us what the question is.

Comment: Youtube video was just an example. How can I be any more concise and direct with my question?

My question is 
• Binary search algorithm has the time complexity of "O((logn)/(log2))" 

• but often said base 2 does not matter and simplified to "O(log(n))."

• Why does base 2 not matter?

Comment: Edit your question and include the above text directly.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t really matters, due the fact that you can represent the log in any base to another base multiplied by a constant c.
See [this](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/logrules5.htm)